# Screen uses 99% of battery

Tags: battery, battery-life, screen, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Galaxy Ace S5830. I tried using many different Jelly Bean and KitKat ROMs, and with each one (clean installs, without additional apps) my battery behaves weird. When the screen is turned on, even on the lowest brightness, it drains the battery very, very fast. I think with the screen turned on I can't get more than hour of battery life.

But when the screen is off, I can, for example, listen to the music for hours and hours and battery behaves normal.

And what is also interesting, whenever I go to Battery Stats, it shows Screen as 99% user, and sometimes it shows WiFi as 1%.

EDIT: Important addition: When my battery gets drained and I put it to the charger, it gets fully charged for few minutes! I tried wiping battery stats before and after every ROM installation, tried using Battery Calibration app, but nothing helps!

So what should I do to get my battery to behave normally?

Comment: It could very well be the light sensor reading by way of the kernel driver that is faulty or perhaps needs calibrating, which is affecting the autobrightness of the screen? Or possibly a known issue with the ROM in which it is not releasing the wakelock for the screen? Check with your respective forum where you got the ROM from?

Comment: As I said, i tried numerous different ROMs, and it's same...
Also brightness is set to lowest level, autobrightness is turned off.

Comment: And quite possibly all those ROMs are using the same or derivative of that kernel that has the issue.

Comment: I've checked the forums, and nobody has this problem..otherwise, I don't think people would use those ROMs, right?

Comment: are you running an app that is chewing up the battery - use BetterBatteryStats to find the culprit?

Comment: There is nothin in Battery stats except Screen and sometimes WiFi. None of the apps. OK, I'll try betterbatterystats

Comment: @kecman BBS is good app to find out what is eating up your battery with wakelocks and also Gsam battery monitor do that job with easy interface.

Comment: I tried both apps, and both of them say that apps use 0% of battery, and screen uses 99%... WiFi uses 1%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed stock 2.3.3 ROM and now everything is fine...I will back it up, and then try experimenting with some newer ROMs :) Thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 1):

From your answer (phone charged again in a few minutes) I'd say there is a  problem with either your battery capacity or your battery stats (either the phone thinks the battery is empty while it isn't, or it thinks it's fully charged when it's not (and so it's emptied again very quickly).

The screen is always a big battery consumer (I never seen it under 40% on my phone) so if your battery life is reduced, it can drain it completely in a couple of hours.

What I'd recommend is to try to charge the battery for a long time after the phone has drained it, like overnight. You may want to try another charger also since there is always the possibility that something had gone wrong with yours.

If it doesn't help and you know someone with the same phone, try swapping the batteries (after both are fully charged):

- If your phone still die in one hour, then you definitely have something consuming too much battery. Try looking into the number of wakelocks as recommended in the comments (also you may try to revert to stock ROM. If the issue is still there, there may be a hardware failure causing this issue)
- If the other phone die in one hour and your is still good, it means you're battery wasn't fully charged. If this is the case, try to charge it again on the other phone and do the test again:

  - if the battery works fine the second time, there is an issue with your phone which doesn't charge batteries the right way. In this case I'm not sure what you can do (that may also be caused by a hardware issue)
  - if it still doesn't work for more than one hour, then you just need a new battery

Answer (score -1):

Try a complete clean installation. I mean wipe 
system
Data 
Cache 
D-Cache
 Then install the is and gapps only. Probably something stable. Then test it for 2 days .